# Foreach can throw an InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, foreach, language-design

Imagine the following code:

```
class foreach_convert
{
    public static void method2()
    {
        List<IComparable> x = new List<IComparable>();
        x.Add(5);

        foreach (string s in x)
        {
            //InvalidCastException in runtime
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder, why is this foreach behavior so... not C#-like?
What happens here is an implicit cast to a subclass, which is error-prone and seems to be banned in every other place in the language. Or am I not right?

P.S. The reason I'm asking is that I had a bug in the similar code in my project, where I used to iterate through a custom Collection from an external library, which was called like `SomeTypeCollection`, but in fact provided a collection of base type items and could have contained items of `SomeOtherType`. My fault, but still neither the language, nor the compiler provided any explicit hints/warnings, which is quite unusual for C#...

Comment: Heh, I first ran into this when I was hoping (not really expecting) foreach would implicitly filter the objects in the collection based on their type.  Think about how it reads, "For each string in collection."  To me, this reads like, "For everything in collection that's a string, do something."  It would then ignore anything that wasn't a string.

Comment: For history: Analyzer for this got rejected by dotnet/runtime team: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/4479

Comment: Update: New `IDE0210` analyzer was [created to detect this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/60120), and will be introduced in VS2022 17.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Think back to before generics... `foreach` had to cast so that you could do sensible things like:

```
foreach (string x in names)
{
    // ...
}
```

instead of:

```
foreach (object tmp in names)
{
    string x = (string) tmp;
    // ...
}
```

The latter is just icky, IMO. Providing an implicit cast is unlike the rest of the language, but makes it much easier to use in the vast majority of cases.

I *suspect* that if C# had had generics *and* extension methods to start with (so we could use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)) that `foreach` wouldn't be specified in quite the same way.

Note that there's even more oddness in `foreach`: the type doesn't have to implement `IEnumerable` at all. So long as it has a `GetEnumerator` method which returns something which in turn has `MoveNext()` and `Current`, the C# compiler is happy. This meant you could implement a "strongly typed iterator" (to avoid boxing) before generics.

Comment: Right. I suspected thats a heritage from the very first C# and making it strongly-typed now is a breaking change... 

[grumble] still, there could have been a warning or just a note in MSDN :-)

Comment: Okay, more refreshed now, and capable of understanding... well... words... don't think my answer added anything that isn't said here :)

Comment: They could build in relevant functionality without generics instead of implementing this ridiculous implicit cast.

Answer (score 9):

With C# 3 I'm using **var** - so I get the compiler warnings.

Comment: Good point. Using var in foreach can save you from that bug, as it would detect the exact type of the collection you are iterating over.

Answer (score 4):

foreach works on IEnumerable, which returns objects of type **object**. For every item, the object will be cast to the type you provided.

Unless you use **var** in C# 3.0. Then the type will be taken from `IEnumerable<T>`, if it is implemented by the collection.

Comment: That gives the impression that foreach (int x in List<int>) would box and then unbox - which is doesn't. The C# compiler uses IEnumerable<T> in preference to IEnumerable where it's available.

Comment: you're right about the typed interface. Sometimes the C# specs are a little inconsistent: it seems that the foreach construct is the only thing in C# that allows covariance and contravariance.