# Do "type-safe" and "strongly typed" mean the same thing?

Tags: c#, types

Do "type-safe" and "strongly typed" mean the same thing?

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, not necessarily - although it depends on your definition of the terms, and there are no very clear and widely accepted definitions.

For instance, dynamic programming languages are often type safe, but not strongly typed. In other words, there's no compile-time type information determining what you can and can't do with a type, but at execution time the runtime makes sure you don't use one type as if it were another.

For example, in C# 4.0, you can do:

```
dynamic foo = "hello";
dynamic length = foo.Length; // Uses String.Length at execution time
foo = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
length = foo.Length; // Uses Array.Length at execution time
dynamic bar = (FileStream) foo; // Fails!
```

The last line is the key to it being type-safe: there's no safe conversion from an int array to a `FileStream`, so the operation fails - instead of treating the bytes of the array object *as if* they were a `FileStream`.

EDIT: C# is normally both "strongly typed" (as a language) and type safe: the compiler won't let you attempt to make arbitrary calls on an object, and the runtime won't let you perform inappropriate conversions.

I'm not entirely sure where unsafe code fits in - I don't know enough about it to comment, I'm afraid.

Dynamic typing in C# 4 allows weakly typed but still type-safe code, as shown above.

Note that `foreach` performs an implicit conversion, making it a sort of hybrid:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add("foo");

foreach (FileStream stream in list)
{
    ...
}
```

This will compile (there was [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949798) on this recently) but will fail at execution time. Ironically, that's because you're *trying* to be strongly typed with respect to the `stream` variable, which means you have to perform a cast on the result of the iterator.

Comment: Jon, can u pls  define/ explain a bit(if u have time) with respect to C#.

Comment: Hm, sounds like your definition of “type-safe” simply means the execution engine won’t access a piece of data thinking it’s the wrong type. I’m surprised at this, because by that definition, C# generics don’t add any type-safety compared to using non-generic ArrayList, for exampe. Would you say that generics are an example only of strong typing, but not type safety?

Comment: @Timwi: The CLR provides the type safety in both cases, but you can look at it at a higher level: if I have to cast the results of extracting a value from an `ArrayList`, that cast can fail. It will fail in a fairly safe way, but the act of "get string value from list" is still riskier than it would be with a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly-typed_programming_language) wikipedia entry, here's an extract:

> Benjamin C. Pierce, author of Types
>   and Programming Languages and Advanced
>   Types and Programming Languages, says,
>   "I spent a few weeks... trying to sort
>   out the terminology of "strongly
>   typed," "statically typed," "safe,"
>   etc., and found it amazingly
>   difficult.... The usage of these terms
>   is so various as to render them almost
>   useless."

Answer (score 1):

"Type Safe" means that there's no casting involved and no run-time type errors can occur.

Some people argue that "Strongly Typed" mean nothing, or "it's good", or "i'm comfortable with it".

Anyway, "Type Safe" relates to a portion of code or API, when "Strongly Typed" refers to a whole language or platform.

Comment: Actually, type safety doesn't imply that type checking is performed at compile-time. As long as it's performed *somewhere*, then it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

They are the basically same, it's just a matter of interpretation:

From wikipedia:

> [Type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety):
>
> Type safety is synonymous with one of the many definitions of strong typing; but type safety and dynamic typing are mutually compatible. A dynamically typed language such as Smalltalk can be seen as a strongly typed language with a very permissive type system where any syntactically correct program is well-typed; as long as its dynamic semantics ensures that no such program ever "goes wrong" in an appropriate sense, it satisfies the definition above and can be called type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

ype safe means preventing programs from accessing memory outside the bounds of an object's public properties. When code is not type-safe, unwanted side effects can occur. Type-safety is important for assembly isolation and security enforcement. When code is type- safe, the common language runtime can completely isolate assemblies from each other