# Why is the C# compiler happy with double IEnumerable<T> and foreach T?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable

I know this code does not work (and have no problems writing it in a way that will work). 
I was wondering how the compiler can build with out any errors. And you get run time errors if you where to run it? ( assuming data was not null )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Class1
{
    public void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> data = null;

        foreach(Foo foo in data){
            foo.Bar();
        }
    }

}

public class Foo {
    public void Bar() { }
}
```

Comment: Resharper catches it with a `Suspicious cast` warning. Still compiles tho.

Comment: @user2864740 It's rather like `.Cast<Foo>`, but it's still only *like* that, not exactly what's happening.

Comment: I guess it is because IEnumerable is a generic class that accepts any class. Since IEnumerable is a class, there is nothing wrong for the compiler.

Comment: @user2864740 IT would throw `System.InvalidCastException` in runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `foreach` does not do compile time checking in your specific case. If you built working code you get [a `InvalidCastException` at run-time](http://ideone.com/GmyzWt).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var item = new Foo();
            var inner = new List<Foo>();
            var outer = new List<List<Foo>>();

            inner.Add(item);
            outer.Add(inner);

            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> data = outer;

            foreach (Foo foo in data)
            {
                foo.Bar();
            }
        }

    }


    public class Foo
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

doing `foreach (Foo foo in data)` is equivalent to calling

```
IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)data).GetEnumerator();
Foo foo; //declared here in C# 4 and older
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    //Foo foo; //declared here in C# 5 and newer

    foo = (Foo)enumerator.Current; //Here is the run time error in your code.

    //The code inside the foreach loop.
    {
        foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

So you see it does not care what type you passed in, as long as the `foo = (Foo)enumerator.Current;` call succeeds.

---

The reason it does not throw any compile time errors is `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That means I am allowed to pass any class that is based on `Foo` or more derived from `Foo`. So if I could potentially make a 2nd class that inherits from `Foo` that would also support `IEnumerable<Foo>` and have my list contain that instead it would cause the cast to fail.

```
//This code compiles fine in .NET 4.5 and runs without throwing any errors.
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var item = new Baz();
        var inner = new List<Baz>();
        inner.Add(item);

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> data = inner;

        foreach (Foo foo in data)
        {
            foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
    }
}

public class Baz : Foo, IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<Foo> IEnumerable<Foo>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However if you mark `Foo` as `sealed` the compiler now knows that no more derived classes could exist and then will throw the compiler error

Comment: +1. Exactly. Should also note that if he changes it to `foreach (var foo in data)`, then the compiler will do the type checking.

Comment: +1. This answer is spot on. I also like the comment above suggesting to use `var` in a `foreach` declaration. The reason why it throws an error when trying to cast to a string, is because the compiler knows those types are incompatible. As a counter, this works: `foreach(Foo2 foo in data)` where `Foo2` is another class defintion

Comment: @Xenolightning Yes, that's right. And *the compiler knows those types are incompatible* because `string` is marked as `sealed`.

Comment: The class `Foo` is not sealed. One can derive from it and make a `CrazyFoo` which implements `IEnumerable<Foo>`. Then the `data` of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>>` may actually yield `CrazyFoo` instances, and the original `foreach` would be valid.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I just added a example of that.

Comment: The covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>` is not strictly necessary. Also in C# 3 and earlier, when generic types couldn't be covariant, it was possible to derive from `Foo` and implement the exact (closed generic) interface desired. Edit: Just make your `inner` a list-of-`Foo`, and still add a `Baz` item, and it should be fine in C# 2.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specified a type explicitly, each iteration of `foreach` will attempt to cast (at runtime) the current item to `Foo`.  It is no different than writing this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> data = null;
foreach (object item in data)
{
    Foo foo = (Foo)item;
    foo.Bar();
}
```

Or more directly, this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> data = null;
Foo foo = (Foo)data;
```

The compiler doesn't complain for the same reason it doesn't complain about a cast to or from an interface: it *cannot prove* that the cast is invalid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12335905/1001985) for an example of why).

Note that, in contrast, if you work with a concrete class instead of the interface `IEnumerable`, then you *will* get a compile-time error.  For example:

```
IEnumerable<List<Foo>> data = null;

foreach(Foo foo in data){  // compile-time error here: "cannot convert List<Foo> to Foo"
    foo.Bar();
}
```

Comment: It is different. Your code would throw `NullRefenceException`, when his throws `System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that's just the difference between `(Foo)data` (throws exception) and `data as Foo` (returns null).  It's an important distinction, but tangential to the question.

Comment: It's possible for a type to be usable in `foreach(Foo foo in data)` without implementing `IEnumerable<Foo>`.  I don't know that such a thing would necessarily be possible if `Foo` was a sealed type that didn't implement `IEnumerable<Foo>`, but the aforementioned "foreach" statement will use compile-time duck-typing to find a `GetEnumerator` method which returns a type that has a `MoveNext` method that returns `bool` and a `Current` property which returns a `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question! this is an open issue I read about it from @Jon Skeet :
[Do "type-safe" and "strongly typed" mean the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969088/do-type-safe-and-strongly-typed-mean-the-same-thing)
and I have read also some blog in msdn. @slaks blog also nice
http://blog.slaks.net/2011/09/c-is-not-type-safe.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make the compile time error happen by marking your `Foo` class as `sealed`:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public void Bar() { }
}
```

Otherwise, compiler cannot be sure that conversion is possible.