# Why I don't get syntax error in this sample code?

Tags: c#, casting, syntax-error, igrouping

Just trying some basics with C# Lookup collection and found, that this simple example compile fine, even **IGrouping** interface should have **TElement** set as int.

```
string txt = "Hello world!";
ILookup<char, int> occurrences = Enumerable.Range(0, txt.Length).ToLookup(i => txt[i], i => i);

foreach (IGrouping<char, string> values in occurrences)
    Console.WriteLine($"{values.Key}: {string.Join(", ", values)}");
```

Obviously, I get run-time error on invalid cast. But I expected, that this is work for compiler...

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Can we settle for [this question and these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20205068/717732) then? That's a literal one. Yup, although the **title** is odd, the question and semantics/meaning/.. are the same.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: much better, yes...that seems a lot more like this question. I think Scott went a little in the weeds near the end of his answer with the business about covariance, but otherwise it's a reasonable facsimile of this Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems here is the rule that the compiler uses:

> If the compiler can see that the value type or sealed class does not
>   implement or inherit the type the programmer is trying to cast
>   to/from, the cast is illegal at compile-time.

(Thanks to Jeppe Stig Nielsen for mentioning this in comments.)

Here is the result of compiling `foreach (XXXX values in occurrences)` if you use either of below options instead of `XXXX` in your example. Pay attention `occurrences` is of type `ILookup<char, int>` which is derived from `IGrouping<char, int>`.

- `public class MyClass { }` Compiles
- `public sealed class MyClass { }` Compile-Time Error
- `public sealed class MyClass : IGrouping<char, int> {...}` Compiles
- `public sealed class MyClass : IGrouping<char, string> {...}` Compile-Time Error
- `public struct MyStruct {}` Compile-Time Error
- `public struct MyStruct : IGrouping<char, string> {...}`  Compile-Time Error
- `public struct MyStruct : IGrouping<char, int> {...}` Compiles

Here is a good blog [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/07/18/duck-notation/) by Krzysztof Cwalina that describes how Duck typing in used in foreach:

C#’s foreach operator already uses duck typing. This might be surprising to some, but to support foreach in C# you don’t need to implement `IEnumerable`! All you have to do is:

Provide a public method `GetEnumerator` that takes no parameters and returns a type that has two members: a) a method `MoveMext` that takes no parameters and return a Boolean, and b) a property `Current` with a getter that returns an Object.

Comment: The reason there cannot be a compile-time error, is that we use interfaces. The compiler knows it has an `IGrouping<char, int>` (from the `Current` property type), but whatever class implements this, could in principle implement `IGrouping<char, string>` as well. Anyone can write a class that implements both of these. Since the compiler cannot rule out that the actual elements yielded are all like that, it is allowed. My recommendation is to use `var` in all `foreach` statements.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: _"could in principle implement IGrouping<char, string> as well."_ -- but if the `GetEnumerator()` method called doesn't enumerate that interface, it doesn't help. The interface compatibility is a complete red-herring. _"Since the compiler cannot rule out..."_ -- but, again...only because that was the specific choice of the developers for the `foreach` statement. When generics were introduced, the spec could have changed to require direct type compatibility instead of using duck-typing (not casting to an expected interface as your comment implies...again, red-herring).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: _"My recommendation is to use var in all foreach statements."_ -- ugh, really? That would completely negate the usefulness of even type compatibility via duck-typing, as then you'd have to write explicit casts yourself any time the collection type doesn't exactly match your desired loop variable type.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I don't thing it's because of using interfaces. If it was the reason, then the statement `foreach (MyStruct values in occurrences)` was valid because `MyStruct` may implement that interface too. But if you use a value type in the example, you will receive a compile-time error.

Comment: As I said in a comment to a now deleted answer, _For example `foreach (string values in occurrences)` with `occurrences` as in the question, must not compile (`string` is `sealed` and does not implement `IGrouping<char, int>`)._

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I said `struct MyStruct`. It's not `sealed` and can implement interfaces.

Comment: @PeterDuniho A statement like `foreach (SpecificType val in e) { /* ... */ }` is allowed if and only if `foreach (var x in e) { var val = (SpecificType)x; /* ... */ }` is allowed, and it is equivalent. But the latter emphasizes the explicit cast that exists. With Linq one can also use `foreach (var val in e.Cast<SpecificType>()) { /* ... */ }` which also makes it quite clear there is a cast involved. I absolutely agree this is just a choice of the language designers! My example with `string` shows that not _any_ explicit cast is allowed at compile-time. There must be a chance it could go well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei While a struct cannot have the `sealed` modifier (would be redundant), any struct (or enum) is sealed in the sense that no type can inherit from it. The rules for explicit casts are the same for `struct` and `sealed class`. If the compiler can see that the value type or `sealed class` does not implement or inherit the type the programmer is trying to cast to/from, the cast is illegal at compile-time. There are other things that can be ruled out at compile-time, such as a cast between two `class` types neither of which inherits from the other (and no user-defined conversion exists).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I think it's convincing: *If the compiler can see that the value type or sealed class does not implement or inherit the type the programmer is trying to cast to/from, the cast is illegal at compile-time.*

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: _"the latter emphasizes the explicit cast that exists"_ -- but the cast is on the individual values returned, not the collection object itself. All the talk about interfaces is just a red herring; what really matters is that there's a `GetEnumerator()` method and that the object returns has the requisite members (`MoveNext()` and `Current`). Yes, in the case of types where the compiler can be sure of the implemented interfaces, it can do additional checking; but this is a nicety and not the _why_ for the question at hand (i.e. why there's _not_ a compile-time error).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Maybe I was not clear. `foreach (MyStruct values in occurrences)` ___is___ allowed if `MyStruct` really implements `IGrouping<char, int>`. The construct `foreach (MyNonSealedClass values in occurrences)` is always allowed, because some assembly the compiler does not know, might derive from `MyNonSealedClass` and have the inheriting class implement this interface.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think we agree. In this case, the type of `Current` is `IGrouping<char, int>`. The compiler cannot inspect the body of the `get` accessor of `Current`. The programmer said `IGrouping<char, string>`. Now, that is a different type. Is there an __implicit__ cast from `IGrouping<char, int>` to `IGrouping<char, string>`? No. Is there an __explicit__ cast from `IGrouping<char, int>` to `IGrouping<char, string>`? Yes (and it may succeed in some cases, for example in the first five iterations of the loop it could go well, then fail in the sixth).

Comment: The language designers decided (for historical reasons (C# 1 had no generic types)) that this be allowed if only an _explicit_ conversion exists. They ___could___ have dictated the stronger requirement that an _implicit_ conversion must exist, but they did not, and this can be confusing to some people. It is part of the language specification that explicit conversions do not exist in all cases; I do not think I would call that a "nicety". C# is a type-safe language.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You: _but the cast is on the individual values returned, not the collection object itself_ Absolutely! If you know you can cast once on the collection object level, I have no problem with that. As in `foreach (var val in (SpecialEnumerable)e)`. This is not the most usual case, of course.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for your comments, I tested some cases and I can confirm you are right. So I edited the answer based on your comment.