# Any advantage to use implicitly type var

Tags: c#, .net

I am not accustomed to use **Var** implicitly typed variable. Anyone can let me know the advantage to use such variable?

Comment: Though technically, you ask a different kind of question, please look at [any](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[C%23]+var) of the other questions and answers relating to the keyword `var`.  Your question might be considered a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430831/anyone-found-a-use-of-var-other-than-for-linq) one.

Comment: I wonder if you would get different answers by swapping the bias in the title to "Any advantage to explicitly spelling out types?" :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is that it's a short hand for long types...Such as:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> myList = getList();
```

Can be simplified to:

```
var myList = getList();
```

Comment: Be careful of just exchanging existing code with var, it can come back and bite you. Consider this: var list = new List<string>(); list.Reverse(); --- and then --- IList<string> list = new List<string>(); list.Reverse(); both examples compiles fine, but only the first example will actually reverse the content of the list. In the second sample the compiler will use the Reverse() extension-method on IEnumerable and its immutable which means it returns a reversed list, while the first example modifies the list.

Comment: Or the other way around: IList<string> list = new List<string>(); list.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(); --- and then --- var list = new List<string>(); list.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(); Here in the second example the compiler will fail since the var infers to the concrete class List, which already has a Reverse() method, while it will use the extension method on the first example. So var can also be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Annonymous types:

```
var person = new { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" };
```

Answer (score 2):

Under normal use, 'var' is entirely optional and equivalent to manually specifying the type.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

However, the 'var' keyword is needed for [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), which I've normally used in conjunction with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I specifically find it much easier to read this:

```
foreach(var dbitem in context.usp_GetUserAndAccountData())
{
    txtUserName.Text = dbitem.UserName;
    // ...
}
```

Than this:

```
foreach(ISingleResult<usp_GetUserAndAccountDataResult> dbitem in context.usp_GetUserAndAccountData())
{
    txtUserName.Text = dbitem.UserName;
    // ...
}
```

For me, regardless of what I explicitly define `dbitem`, I'll still do the same actions; so `var` here is priceless!
And the beauty of it all is that IntelliSense will still list you all the members of the expected type on the other end (such as `UserName` in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Better code readability. Especially used with constructors and long type name:

```
var anArray = new String[3];
var iStream = new InputStream(...);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Comment: And even for variables that should be initialized as nulls you can use the var keyword like this: var dict = default(Dictionary<string, int>);

Comment: The idea of readability depends. In your example above, it's true. That is more readable. However, in a situation where you're calling a function in which the return interface or type isn't clear, it can be difficult to know -- without reviewing the method in question -- what type you are dealing with and therefore, I argue that is less readiable. Not a reason to not use var but I don't use it because it's readable alone...

Answer (score 1):

Just be mindful that using var is not always what it seems (though mostly is). An example is this:

dataList is a DataList control on a webform

```
foreach (var item in dataList.Items)
{
    // item is of type System.Object
}

foreach (DataListItem item in dataList.Items)
{
    // item is of type DataListItem
}
```

Comment: Thats just because of the pre .net 2 world before generics did exist, and not a limitation of the var keyword. Would be nice to see MS revisit all of those collections and add a IEnumerable<T> interface to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it was created for the purpose of anonymous types (ala Kugels example):

```
var person = new { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" };
```

However since I discovered it I have to admit I have found it quite useful in day-to-day use when dealing with longer type names, for example:

```
var aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<ReallyLongTypeName>>();
// vs
Dictionary<string, List<ReallyLongTypeName>> aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<ReallyLongTypeName>>();
```

Another side effect is that type names can change (or be replaced with other types), but code that uses `var` wont' break, for example:

```
var item = this.GetItem();
this.Name = item.Name;
this.Age = item.Age;
```

As long as the return value from GetItem always has a property `Name` and a property `Age` (which are compatible with the properties on `this`) then `GetItems` can return an entirely different object and the above code will still compile. (But be careful - existing compiled assemblies can't use the same trick!)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, to me a *real* advantage is when dealing with external code, to decouple the variable type from the actual method signature.

Consider this interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   List<Foo> GetSomething();
}
```

And say you have two lines of code:

```
List<Foo> foos = fooRepo.GetSomething();
var foos2 = fooRepo.GetSomething();
```

Same result for above two lines. (`List<Foo>` returned).

Now if changed the interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   Dictionary<bool,Foo> GetSomething();
}
```

The first line would now throw a compiler error, the second would not:

```
List<Foo> foos = fooRepo.GetSomething(); // error - can't convert from Dictionary<bool,Foo> to List<Foo>
var foos2 = fooRepo.GetSomething(); // works!
```

This is really handy when working with repositories/other projects where interface contracts/method signatures can change.

Yes you still have to recompile the classes, but you don't have to go back and change all the code that referenced the old return type.

Comment: If an external library changes their signatures you would still have to recompile all of your libraries, since the var is translated into a concrete type at compile time, which then wouldn't match anymore. I still agrees that a simple recompile without any changes in code is nice, but just to make it clear since one could get the impression that var works on the runtime level by reading your last line.

Comment: Yes - @BurningIce, excellent point. Yes, you need to recompile - the point i was making was you don't need to go back and change all the code.