# Why does compiler let this slip?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Foreach can throw an InvalidCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949798/foreach-can-throw-an-invalidcastexception)

Consider the following block of code

```
public class Base
{
}

public class DerivedLeft : Base
{
}

public class DerivedRight : Base
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> list = new List<Base> { new DerivedLeft(), new DerivedRight() };
        foreach (DerivedLeft dl in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dl.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the cast from Base to DerivedLeft in foreach statement. This compiles fine (Visual Studio 2010), without any error or even warning.
Obviously, on the second loop-iteration we will get an InvalidCastException. 
If I was asked a question about reaction of compiler to such code, I would without a doubt say, that compiler won't let this go unnoticed and produce at least a warning.
But apparently it doesn't. So, why does the compiler let this slip through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doing an implicit cast.  Check out this post on the same topic for an excellent explanation by Jon Skeet:

[Foreach can throw an InvalidCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949798/foreach-can-throw-an-invalidcastexception)

Answer (score 2):

Because list is of type `List<Base>` and the variable `dl` in the foreach loop is of type DerivedLeft which has Base as base class. So it *can* work during runtime, but it does not *have* to. The compiler isn't checking the initialization of your list.

Comment: I think the compiler does check the initialization  ....e.g. if i put MyOtherClass there so there is a compile time exception

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, the compiler checks if the initialization is correct, but it doesn't check if only matching elements are in it when he reaches the foreach loop.

Comment: It's only checking the initialization as far as `DerivedLeft` isa `Base` and `DerivedRight` isa `Base`. From the point of view of `list` they are all `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Expecting the compiler to raise an error on this is like expecting it to raise an error on this:

```
Base b = new DerivedRight();
DerivedLeft d = (DerivedLeft)b;
```

Comment: in fact the compiler will raise an error on this, since you didn't provide the variable name for DerivedLeft :)

Comment: In fairness, the implicit cast involved in `foreach` isn't as obvious, unless one has coded with `C#` for .NET1.0 or 1.1, in which the lack of generics meant it would have been much more awkward not to have the implicit cast, as every `foreach` that didn't deal with `object` would have needed one.