# foreach and generics compiler issue

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction, foreach

I used an interface and class similar to following:

```
public interface IIdentity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Identity : IIdentity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I was creating instances of the `Identity` class and adding it to `List<Identity>` (later referred to as instances creation block).

```
var identities = new List<IIdentity>();
identities.Add( new Identity { Id = 1 } );
identities.Add( new Identity { Id = 2 } );
identities.Add( new Identity { Id = 3 } );
```

and then using the `identities` as follows:

```
foreach ( IIdentity identity in identities )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Plug-in: {0}", identity.Id.ToString() );
}
```

Recently I needed to add more data about `IIdentity` instances without making any modification to `IIdentity` and `Identity`. Therefore I added following class:

```
public class Wrapper<T> where T : class
{
    public T WrappedObject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

and replaced the instances creation block with following:

```
var identities = new List<Wrapper<IIdentity>>();
identities.Add( new Wrapper<IIdentity> { WrappedObject = new Identity { Id = 1 }, Name = "John", Order = 1 } );
identities.Add( new Wrapper<IIdentity> { WrappedObject = new Identity { Id = 2 }, Name = "Jane", Order = 2 } );
identities.Add( new Wrapper<IIdentity> { WrappedObject = new Identity { Id = 3 }, Name = "Joe", Order = 3 } );
```

I was expecting that I would still have to make some modification to foreach block to make the application compile. However, application compiled successfully and threw `System.InvalidCastException` when it was run.

As it is visible from provided code, `Wrapper` does not implement `IIdentity` interface.

However, the compiler was complaining if one of two modifications was made:

1. `Wrapper` class is sealed.
2. Line 1 is replaced with line 2

Line 1:

```
foreach ( IIdentity identity in identities )
```

Line 2:

```
foreach ( var identity in identities )
```

The question is why did compiler successfully compile application when modification 1 or 2 are not in place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach can throw an InvalidCastException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949798/foreach-can-throw-an-invalidcastexception)

Comment: @Steven: That question is not a dupe by a long shot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler sees that the type of `identities` is `List<Wrapper<IIdentity>>`, and it can see that `Wrapper<T>` does *not* implement `IIdentity`. However, by itself that's not enough to produce a compile-time error because there might be a derived class like this somewhere:

```
class DerivedWrapper<T> : Wrapper<T>, IIdentity { ... }
```

Instances of `DerivedWrapper` can legitimately be put inside `identities`, so the compiler has to try to cast `identity` to `IIdentity` at runtime and throw an exception if this fails.

The two modifications affect this in different ways:

1. If `Wrapper` is `sealed` then the compiler knows there can be no such derived class so the runtime cast can never succeed; helpfully, it promotes this to a compile time error.
2. If implicit typing with `var` is used then the compiler resolves `var` to the static type of `identity`, which in this instance is `Wrapper<IIdentity>`. This means that the loop body tries to access the non-existent member `Wrapper<IIdentity>.Id` member, hence a compile-time error.