# C# type conversion inconsistent?

Tags: c#, types, casting

In C#, I cannot implicitly convert a `long` to an `int`.

```
long l = 5;
int i = l;  // CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This produces said error. And rightly so; if I do that, I am at risk of breaking my data, due to erroneous truncation. If I decide that I know what I am doing, then I can always do an explicit cast, and tell the compiler that it's okay to truncate, I know best.

```
int i = (int)l;  // OK
```

However, the same mechanism does not seem to apply when using a `foreach` loop.

```
IList<long> myList = new List<long>();
foreach (int i in myList)
{
}
```

The compiler does not even generate a warning here, even though it is essentially the same thing: an unchecked truncation of a `long` to an `int`, which might very well break my data.

So my question is simply: Why does this `foreach` not create the same error as the variable assignment does?

Comment: I believe the compiler will treat your specification of `int` as an explicit cast when it generates the iterator code. I experience the same occasionally on `DataGridView` rows collection, which when `foreach (var row in grid.Rows)` yields a type of `object` whereas `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)` doesn't.

Comment: [`Casting and Type Conversions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), [`Type Conversion in the .NET Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98bbex99.aspx)

Comment: I would guess that it doesn't create the error because you're doing a `foreach int`, and `long` is an integer type.

Comment: Check section 8.8.4 of the C# language specification to read about the foreach loop. But basically, it is being translated into code that is inserting the cast. (Think how the foreach worked on the old ArrayList, for example, which stored everything as object.)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949798/foreach-can-throw-an-invalidcastexception

Comment: You do an explicit cast by writing `foreach (int i ...`.

Comment: [Link to the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754.aspx), although it's an older version.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Unfortunately that guess is incorrect, otherwise `int i = (long)2147483648;` also wouldn't have issues.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Fair enough, I did say it was a guess. :D

Comment: Please don't use the lowercase letter l as a variable name. It is very difficult to distinguish from 1.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350495/whats-going-on-behind-the-scene-of-the-foreach-loop

Answer (score 31, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in July of 2013](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/). Thanks for the great question!

> Why does this foreach not create the same error as the variable assignment does?

"Why" questions are difficult to answer because I don't know the "real" question you're asking. So instead of answering that question I'll answer some different questions.

> What section of the specification justifies this behaviour?

As Michael Liu's answer correctly points out, it is section 8.8.4.

> The whole point of an *explicit* conversion is that the conversion must be *explicit* in the code; that's why we have the cast operator; it's waving a big flag that says "there's an explicit conversion right here". This is one of the few times in C# where an explicit conversion is not extant in the code. What factors motivated the design team to invisibly insert an "explicit" conversion?

The `foreach` loop was designed before generics.

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
myList.Add("abc");
myList.Add("def");
myList.Add("ghi");
```

You don't want to have to say:

```
foreach(object item in myList)
{
    string current = (string)item;
```

In a world without generics you have to *know ahead of time* what types are in a list, and *you almost always do have that knowledge*. But this information is not captured in the type system. Therefore, you have to tell the compiler somehow, and you do that by saying

```
foreach(string item in myList)
```

This is your assertion to the compiler that the list is full of strings, just like a cast is an assertion that a particular item is a string.

You are completely correct that this is a misfeature in a world with generics. Since it would be breaking to change it now, we're stuck with it.

The feature is quite confusing; when I first started programming C# I assumed that it had the semantics of something like:

```
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (!(enumerator.Current is string) continue;
    string item = (string)enumerator.Current;
```

That is, "for each object of type string in this list, do the following", when it really is "for each object in this list assert that the item is a string and do the following..." (If the former is what you actually want then use the `OfType<T>()` extension method.)

The moral of the story is: languages end up with weird "legacy" features when you massively change the type system in version 2.

> Should the compiler produce a warning for this case in modern code, where generics are being used?

I considered it. Our research showed that

```
foreach(Giraffe in listOfMammals)
```

is *so common* that most of the time we'd be giving a warning for correct code. That creates trouble for everyone who compiles with "warnings as errors" turned on, and it's generally speaking badness to have a warning on code that is yes maybe a bit smelly but *actually correct*. We decided to not pursue the warning.

> Are there other situations where the C# compiler invisibly inserts explicit conversions?

Yes. In fact someone asked a question about that just a few hours after this one:

[Compiler replaces explicit cast to my own type with explicit cast to .NET type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425856/compiler-replaces-explicit-cast-to-my-own-type-with-explicit-cast-to-net-type/16427263#16427263)

There are some extremely obscure interop scenarios where explicit conversions are inserted as well.

Comment: In C# 1.0, an `InvalidCastException` occurs if you enumerate an `ArrayList` of `long` values with an `int` variable, and in C# 4.0, an `InvalidCastException` occurs if enumerate the LINQ query `from int i in myList select i`. Basically, I think it's the automatic *numeric* conversion from `long` to `int` that's surprising; I would expect only explicit reference and unboxing conversions to be performed.

Comment: @Michael, with a non-generic arraylist, you would need `(int)(long)value` to get a boxed long out, so it makes sense the conversion semantics of foreach would fail. If using a generic enumerator that exposes T (long), then int is a straightforward conversion.

Comment: I tend to use `var` a lot and as such `foreach (var...` quite often returns `object` even if the collection is strongly typed (usually when working with SharePoint-related stuff). As such, I've accepted that I am making an explicit cast when using `foreach`. :)

Answer (score 13):

As defined in §8.8.4 of the C# 4.0 specification, a `foreach` statement of the form

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

is expanded to

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        V v;
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            v = (V)(T)e.Current; // <-- note the explicit cast to V
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

where `C` is the "collection type" and `T` is the "element type" inferred from `x`.

The cast to `V` (`int` in your case) is what allows your example to compile.

The likely reason for the cast to `V`: in C# 1.0, before generics was added to the language, an explicit cast was usually needed anyway when enumerating through a collection like `ArrayList`, because the compiler could not automatically figure out the type of values in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is `foreach` does an explicit cast behind the scenes. Another example:

```
    public class Parent { }
    public class Child : Parent { }

    IList<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>()
    {
        new Parent()
    };
    foreach (Child child in parents) { }
```

This will also not generate a compiler error, but will throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.