# Why is an double int variable possible when iterating over a double enumerable in a `foreach` loop?

Tags: c#

Consider the following loop ([live example](https://ideone.com/R3RONl)):

```cs
foreach (int x in doubleEnumerable) { /* Do sth. */ }
```

I'm confused why I don't get an error, that the conversion from double to int needs to be made explicit. It strikes me as inconsistent because the following doesn't work, but seems equivalent:

```cs
foreach (double tmp in doubleEnumerable) {
  int x = tmp; // error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
}
```

What's the reason, is it a bug in (or a quirk of) C#?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd put it as a quirk of C#.
It's not an 'implicit conversion' but actually an explicit *cast* under the hood, as explained in the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1395-the-foreach-statement). The TL;DR excerpt is that the loop

```cs
foreach (V v in x) «embedded_statement»
```

is transformed into

```cs
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            «embedded_statement»
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a deliberate, explicit cast (which btw is also the reason why [`foreach` can throw an InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949798/2473926)).

The deeper reason, eludes me, however; probably it's 'for historic reasons'. I'm also not sure why not to introduce a warning in newer lanugage version (which for compatibility may be ignored).

Comment: _"The deeper reason, eludes me, however; probably it's 'for historic reasons'. "_ - **it is**:  if you go back to C# 1.0 before generics, the `IEnumerable` type returned `Object` references, so a cast was necessary. _Annoyingly_, the only way (even today) to have a "cast-less" `foreach`, even with `IEnumerable<T>` is to use `var` instead of a typename `T`, which is hardly ideal.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. But would it not be possible to only include the cast if necessary (i.e., if it is not implicitly convertible)? And in this case at least issue a compiler warning. (I'm not an expert, so it might be a rather stupid question; if so, I beg to excuse.)

Comment: Not that this really answers your question but maybe the 'why' is as simple as language developers had (have) bigger things they'd like to implement.  You can go here (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) and submit your enhancement request.  Or better yet, make a pull request and implement it.

Comment: @Dai: Compare [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANnAJiA1AHwAIBMAjALABQeADAAR5EAsA3OeXgMy0HUAqApgM4JyAb3LVxtDnnrUAkgl4AnCAoAUdNgB46lAHzV+AewCuigMa8AlGImiyEh9QBmhxbwhmAFtXVEa/algDE3MrG0dqOwjxAF9w6jiyGKA===) to [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANnAJiA1AHwAIBMAjALABQeADAAR5EAsA3OeXgMy0HUAqApgM4JyAb3LVxtDnnrUAkgl4AnCAoAUdNgB4A9sABWvAMYIAfNX7aArosO8AlGImiyE19QBm2xbwiGAFtTqRDT81LDmVjb2jm7UzrHiAL4x1MlkiUA). When the range variable's type matches the enumerable's `T` exactly, it doesn't perform a cast. `var` isn't required. That should give some relief.

Comment: @madreflection Right - I meant to say that _if_ the type `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` were to change, _without_ the `foreach` type also being updated, then there's no compiler warning and it'll be a nasty surprise...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Xlea previous answer. I would add some more information on the ability of VS & .NET to produce errors in case you want to avoid the described behaviour.

You could refer to the [Add explicit cast in foreach loop (IDE0220) rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0220).
Using an [`.editorconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files) file you could set an `error` severity level to signal that you doesn't want to add explicit cast.

This is the line to add to your `.editorconfig`

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0220.severity = error
```

But, this setting only works on the severity level managed by the IDE (VS 2022 or VS Code). To avoid the build to compile successfully your code you must also add the [`EnfornceCodeStyleInBuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enforcecodestyleinbuild) option to the project `<PropertyGroup>` tag.

```xml
<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
```

You could also simply set the severity to `warning`, in this case the build process will generate a warning as expected.

For a list of all rules availables you could check [Code-style rules (on MS Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info - I'll certainly give it a try. (No time yet.)